# JSON over POST with curl (to pylons)

Tags: json, post, curl, controller, pylons

I have a pylons controller action that accepts POST

```
@restrict('POST')
def myaction(self):

    payload = json.loads(request.body)
```

I put properly formed JSON (I can do json.loads on it from python command line) in a file.

I am using the following command to send it to the controller:

```
$ curl -F payload=@./myfile -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' -v http://localhost:5000/mycontroller/myaction
```

on the controller side I'm expecting well formed JSON, but instead of getting JSON in *request.body* I'm getting a string with other stuff like

*-----------------------6588b6680ebb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;*

before the string containing a string representation of JSON I sent to myaction

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option `-F` is for multipart content, you should use --data / -d instead:

```
$ curl --data @./myfile -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' -v http://localhost:5000/mycontroller/myaction
```